# Procedural stairs driven by a curve

Tags: scripting, modifiers, rigging, bezier-curves, constraints

The idea is to create procedural stairs that are driven by a 2 point curve (or just 2 empties if possible). The curve/distance between empties controls the amount/length of stairs and the angle. I tried with array modifier but this method doesn't give me desired control. Endgame of this will be stairs for procedural soccer stadium (placed on a bezier circle) adjustable along the whole stadium size